# RoleProvider Getting roles from asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I want to build custom roles. I've created a new class :

```
public class TheRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        DataLayerAccess dal = new DataLayerAccess();
        return dal.GetUserGroups(username);
    }
```

The others methods return

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Below the code of the method GetUserGroups

```
public string[] GetUserGroups(string UserName)
{
    List<UserGroup> listGroup = 
        PostAsyncRestObject<List<UserGroup>, string>(
            "http://my_server/ServiceCommon.svc/GetUserGroups",
            UserName)
        .Result;

    List<string> strGr = new List<string>();
    foreach (UserGroup ug in listGroup)
    {
        strGr.Add(ug.GroupName);
    }

    return strGr.ToArray();
}
```

What I don't understand is why when "PostAsyncRestObject" is called, the browser is waiting for something and I'm not able to get back a result.

If someone can give me some clues to solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: shouldn't that method be async and await on the call? Invoking Result is bound to lead to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `await` the `async` method (and probably change its name to GetUserGroups**Async** as well):

```
public async Task<string[]> GetUserGroupsAsync(string UserName)
{
    List<UserGroup> listGroup = await
        PostAsyncRestObject<List<UserGroup>, string>(
            "http://my_server/ServiceCommon.svc/GetUserGroups",
            UserName).ConfigureAwait(false);

    List<string> strGr = new List<string>();
    foreach (UserGroup ug in listGroup)
    {
        strGr.Add(ug.GroupName);
    }

    return strGr.ToArray();
}
```

The other option would be to replace the call to the asynchronous `PostAsyncRestObject` method with a call to a synchronous method. You shouldn't mix asynchronous and synchronous code like you are doing here.

Comment: Even if I use async or not for the method "GetUserGroupAsync", it doesn't work. The method "public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)" doesn't accept asynchronism

Comment: Don't use PostAsyncRestObject then. Use a sync method instead.